# AWS CDK - Set IDPs to "enabled' state programmatically

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm successfully creating Facebook and Google IDPs in my User Pool, however, they're in a 'disabled' state after running `CDK deploy` and I need to manually go into the UI and click `enabled`. The IDPs do work as expected once enabled.

How can I programmatically set them as `enabled`?

```
this.userPool = new UserPool(this, props.userPoolId, {
  selfSignUpEnabled: true,
  autoVerify: { email: true },
  signInAliases: { email: true },
});

const googleIdp = new UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle(
  this,
  "UserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle",
  {
    userPool: this.userPool,
    // Removed
  }
);

this.userPool.identityProviders.push(googleIdp);

const facebookIdp = new UserPoolIdentityProviderFacebook(
  this,
  "UserPoolIdentityProviderFacebook",
  {
    userPool: this.userPool,
    // Removed
  }
);

this.userPool.identityProviders.push(facebookIdp);

const userPoolClient = new UserPoolClient(this, props.userPoolClientId, {
  userPool: this.userPool,
  generateSecret: false,
  supportedIdentityProviders: [
    UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.GOOGLE,
    UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.FACEBOOK,
  ],
});

userPoolClient.node.addDependency(googleIdp, facebookIdp)
```

I thought I was enabling those values with the `UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.GOOGLE` and `UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.FACEBOOK` line but I might have missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adjusting the order things happen in:

```
userPoolClient.node.addDependency(googleIdp, facebookIdp)

this.userPool.identityProviders.push(googleIdp);
this.userPool.identityProviders.push(facebookIdp);
```

I'm actually not sure why this makes it but I guess you just need to make sure the `userPoolClient` has the correct IDP resources before you push those same IDPs into the `userPool`.

If someone has a better explanation, would love to hear it!